# How to target a specific form on submit if multiple forms are present with same class name in one page using vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm interested in one vanilla JS function that will target the specific form that was submitted while having multiple forms with the same class name on the same page. Using IDs is not an option for each form.

Let's say I have 10 forms like the following on some page:

```
<form class="add_to_cart">
    <div class="btn btn__add_to_cart">Add To Cart</div>
    <input type="hidden" id="some_product_id">
</form>
```

How can I grab with JS (no jQuery please) the specific form on which the `div` element was clicked (I didn't use `button` element on purpose, i'm interested in the `div` option)?

Will really appreciate your help.

Comment: What have you tried and what challenge have you had with that?

Comment: So if you interested in pressing a `div`, for what purpose you need a `form`?

Comment: `this.closest("form")`, however I suspect that you are not using `form`s correctly in the first place. Why do you need multiple `form` elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem is that you are doing this in a more difficult way than it needs to be

If you just do:

```
<form class="add_to_cart">
    <input type='submit' class="btn btn__add_to_cart" value='Add To Cart' />
    <input type="hidden" id="some_product_id">
</form>
```

Clicking the button will submit the correct form.
You can restyle the button using CSS if you wish

BUT...

If you the divs are necessary, you can do something like

```
document.querySelectorAll("DIV").forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.target.closest("form").submit();
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I used `document.querySelectorAll('div.btn.btn__add_to_cart')` to reduce the event listeners (since there probably will be many divs) and I used `$form = e.target.closest('form')` since I didn't really want to submit the specific  form but only to "grab" it with JS. Anyway, thank you. It helped.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do with it but here is a click handler using the classes  `btn` and `btn__add_to_cart` that are a div.

I also added a form submit handler for the closest form that was clicked.

```js
let submitEvent = new CustomEvent("submit", {
  "bubbles": true,
  "cancelable": true
});

function logSubmit(event) {
  console.log(`Form Submitted! Time stamp: ${event.timeStamp}`);
  let button = event.currentTarget.querySelectorAll('input')[0];
  console.log(`Form button ID: ${button.id}`);
  event.preventDefault();
}
var evt = new CustomEvent("submit", {
  "bubbles": true,
  "cancelable": true
});
let allforms = document.querySelectorAll('form.add_to_cart');
Array.from(allforms).forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('submit', logSubmit);
});

function clickedMe(event) {
  console.log(event.currentTarget === this) // logs `true`
  let closestForm = event.currentTarget.closest('form.add_to_cart');
  console.log("My Classes:", this.className);
  closestForm.dispatchEvent(submitEvent);
}
const clickableButtons = document.querySelectorAll(`div.btn.btn__add_to_cart`);
console.log(clickableButtons.length);
Array.from(clickableButtons).forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', clickedMe, false);
});
```

```html
<form class="add_to_cart">
  <div class="btn btn__add_to_cart">Add To Cart</div>
  <input type="hidden" id="some_product_id">
</form>
<form class="add_to_cart">
  <div class="btn btn__add_to_cart">Add To Cart 2</div>
  <input type="hidden" id="some_product_id2">
</form>
```